# Can I build Tuples from IEnumerables using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I've two `IEnumerable<double>`s, that I want to build an `IEnumerable` of `Tuple<int, double, double>` from. `Item1` of the `Tuple` should be the index of the item, `Item2` the value in index-th place in the first collection, and `Item3` the value in index-th place in the second collection. Is this something that can be done easily in Linq?

E.g.

```
var first = new List<double>() { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 };
var second = new List<double>() { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
var result = TupleBuild(first, second);
// result = {(0, 10.0, 1.0), (1, 20.0, 2.0), (2, 30.0, 3.0)}
```

where:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, double, double>> TupleBuild(IEnumerable<double> first, IEnumerable<double> second)
{ 
     // does some funky Linq
}
```

I realise I could write some longhand code for this, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if Linq has this covered.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about with the `Zip` operator and the `Select` overload that provides the index of the element:

```
return first.Zip(second, Tuple.Create)
            .Select((twoTuple, index)
                      => Tuple.Create(index, twoTuple.Item1, twoTuple.Item2));
```

By the way, you might as well then make the method generic:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, TFirst, TSecond>> TupleBuild<TFirst, TSecond>
(IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second) { ... }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Wish I could give you an extra up vote for introducing me to the Zip extension :)

Comment: And I wish I could upvote twice for Zip and the overloaded Select.

Answer (score 1):

A more modern version updated per [`C# 7.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) (based on the answer of @Ani).

This uses the more readable (IMO) tuple syntax without `Tuple.Create`. Also note the return type and the *tuple deconstruction* within the `Select` method.

```
IEnumerable<(int, double, double)> TupleBuild
    (IEnumerable<double> first, IEnumerable<double> second)
    {
        return first
            .Zip(second)
            .Select((tuple, index) =>
            {
                var (fst, snd) = tuple;
                return (index, fst, snd);
            });
    }
```